# Creating a GUI in MATLAB using guide is not updating the m-file?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to create a GUI.  I try and add 3 radio buttons to the GUI and when I hit save the m-file doesn't change...

I can add other entities and the m-file is edited and changed like normal.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet to see where you might be going wrong ? This information is certainly not enough to tell what is wrong with your code.

Comment: That's the thing, he's using GUIDE in Matlab to make the interface - it is a GUI for making GUIs and is meant to automagically generate the m-file to generate the GUI.

Comment: If you start making the GUI, are you able to export it or run it? Are you adding the buttons to a button group, or just placing them on the gui somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete a function that GUIDE creates it wont automatically add it back for you. You need to use the INSPECTOR tool in GUIDE and click the box next to the function to make GUIDE add the function back into your m-file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

GUIDE stores the GUI between a FIG-file with the figure data and an M-file with the callback functions. You may need to add some callbacks for the radio buttons before it will modify the  M-file.